# SSIS Data Flow doesn't copy all columns

Tags: ssis

I want to create a simple `SSIS` `Control flow`. `Data flow` structure is as follows
[image]

Flat File source looks as follows:

[image]

And `OLE DB Destination` file looks as follows:

[image]

Table structure of `WeatherHistoryStaging` is looking as:

[image]

And than I've run packge, but only `Date` column is copied into `WeatherHistoryStaging`  table, other columns are null. Before exetuting `Data Flow` task, I execute `SQL Task`, which deletes `WeatherHistoryStaging` table, that part works fine. Why not all columns are copied from txt file into `WeatherHistoryStaging`  table?

Column mapping of Destination

[image]

Comment: How does the column mapping of the OLE DB Destination look like? Are all the colums mapped to a source column?

Comment: @JodyT, I've added mapping screenshot to the post. Is that right?

Comment: You have only mapped the Date colum. You're ignoring the other 3 columns that's why they're staying NULL. Select the correct source columns instead of <ignore> and it should work.

Comment: @JodyT, I'm new to SSIS and didn't know  about that. Thanks. Post your answer and I'll accept it))

Comment: No problem. I posted the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have only mapped the Date colum. You're ignoring the other 3 columns that's why they're staying `NULL`. Select the correct source columns instead of `<ignore>` and it should work.